# I can't modify clip-path value depending on window.scrollY with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, dom-events, clip-path

I'm trying to modify the clip-path value of an image bases on the scroll. The function works with other properties (I tried with width for exemple) but not for clip-path.

The CSS:

```
#blue-line{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 4rem;
    bottom: -2rem;
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 100%);
}
```

The JS:

```
blueLine = document.getElementById('blue-line')    
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        let currentPosition = window.scrollY
let value = 100 - currentPosition/2
console.log(value)

blueLine.style.clipPath = "inset(0px 0px 0px"+ value +"%);"

let cl= window.getComputedStyle(blueLine).getPropertyValue("clip-path");
console.log(cl)
    })
```

I want the last value of clip-path to decrease with the scroll value. The console.log shows that the value variable changes but the clip-path value isn't changed by the function.

Thanks by advance

Comment: What sort of numbers are you getting for value? I can’t see how they would be valid %s as you haven’t worked them out as a % (e.g. as a percentage of the overall height that could be scrolled).

Comment: `"inset(0px 0px 0px"+ value +"%);"` - there clearly and obviously will be whitespace missing here ...

Comment: @CBroe Yep a whitespace was missing! Adding one after the last 0px makes it work "inset(0px 0px 0px "+ value +"%);" Thanks!